# How to convert excel clmn values to int and add again them with other clmn variables and store back in excel

Tags: excel, vba

```
dim g as int, i as string
range("a1").value = i 
g = 10
range("b1").value = i + g
```

> let A1 = 1
>   Expected B1 = 11 but it is 10

Comment: sorry gave an answer below but it occurs to me, why is i set as a string and not an integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dim g as int, i as string
i = range("a1").value 'assuming that A1 contains 1
g = 10
range("b1").value = i + g
```

2nd line assignment is the wrong way round

Wing

Answer (score 1):

Since i as **String** var ("1"), it should be ..

```
range("b1").value = val(i) + g
```